# Websphere How to remove module using jython

Tags: websphere-8

i'm trying to remove a module from a websphere application.
i need to do it via Jython.

currently i did not find any command to remove a module in easy way.

any one has a simple clear example

Comment: If you want easy way just use the admin console, and update partially application check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_update.html. Much easier than doing via Jython.

Answer (score 0):

[This IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_app.html#txml_config_prop_app__delmod) describes how to use Jython in conjunction with properties files to manage applications and modules, including deletion.

Comment: examples there are horrible, i'm not a expert in WAS :) and looking for a simple example to do a simple thing

WAS is way too complex...

Comment: You asked specifically for a way to do this in Jython, not the simplest way, which I provided.  As pointed out by @Gas above, there may be simpler ways to achieve this.  To your comment about complexity, SO is not the appropriate place for subjective comments about products.